# laravel PackageServiceProvider not found; moving from workbench to vendor

Tags: laravel

This is basically a problem of moving a laravel package from workbench to vendor, but the solutions in other threads have not worked in this case:

I have a package `iateadonut/signup`.

I created a fresh laravel installation (laravel_test), and, just for testing sake, I put `iateadonut/signup` in `laravel_test/workbench/`.

I put `Iateadonut\Signup\SignupServiceProvider`, in the 'providers' array in app.php.

I then run:

```
/laravel_test> php artisan dump-autoload
```

and get:

> Generating optimized class loader
>   Running for workbench [iateadonut/signup]...
>
> My package is successfully installed.

On a fresh installation of laravel (laravel_test), I then put `iateadonut/signup` in larael_test/vendor.

I put `Iateadonut\Signup\SignupServiceProvider`, in the 'providers' array in app.php.

I then run:

```
/laravel_test> php artisan dump-autoload
```

and get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Iateadonut\Signup\SignupServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/html/laravel_test/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 4214
>   {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Iateadonut\Signup\SignupServiceProvider' not found","file":"/var/www/html/laravel_test/bootstrap/compiled.php","line":4214}}

Any idea what could be wrong?

---

Here is a more google friendly version in case someone else is looking for this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Vendor\Package\PackageServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/html/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 4214
>   {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Vender\Package\PackageServiceProvider' not found","file":"/var/www/html/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php","line":4214}}

Comment: I would try commenting out `Iateadonut\Signup\SignupServiceProvider` from the `providers` array in app.php first. Then try `php artisan dump-autoload`. Then uncomment the provider and see if the error still exists.

Comment: Sorry for posting (this has already been answered on stackoverflow).  I just needed to add

 "psr-0": {
  "Iateadonut\\Signup\\": "vendor/iateadonut/signup/src/"
 }

to autoload in app_root/composer.json so it looks like:

 "autoload": {
  "classmap": [
   "app/commands",
   "app/controllers",
   "app/models",
   "app/database/migrations",
   "app/database/seeds",
   "app/tests/TestCase.php"
  ],
  "psr-0": {
   "Iateadonut\\Signup\\": "vendor/iateadonut/signup/src/"
  }
 },

I must have done it incorrectly before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the the `bootstrap/compiled.php` file and try your `composer dumpautoload` again